# auto-detect conditional probabilities in macro

Tags: math-mode, macros

Is it possible to write a macro that detects whether there is a `|` character in its arguments, and expands that to something else?

In concrete terms, I want to be able to use the following definitions simultaneously:

```
\def\P(#1){\Pr\left( #1 \right)}
\def\P(#1|#2){\Pr\left( #1 \mid #2 \right)}
```

Whenever in the text I write a probability `$\P(X)$`, the first definition should be used, whereas `$\P(X|Y)$` should use the second.

If possible, a simple TeX/LaTeX solution is preferred, since many journals put restrictions on usable packages.

I know this could be achieved using simply two different macros. The reason for this question is that the abstract of a paper often ends up printed in plain text (think the arXiv email), and I would like it to be as readable as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can differentiate the argument as you requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\P(#1){\Phelper#1|\relax\Pchoice(#1)}
\def\Phelper#1|#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax\def\Pchoice{\Pone}\else\def\Pchoice{\Ptwo}\fi}
\def\Pone(#1){\Pr\left( #1 \right)}
\def\Ptwo(#1|#2){\Pr\left( #1 \mid #2 \right)}
\def\Pr{\mathbf{Pr}}
\begin{document}
$\P(A)$ or $\P(A|B)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your arguments are always short, then a simpler `\def\P(#1){\Pr(#1)}` may be sufficient for your need.  But since you are using `\left(...\right)`, it might be the case that you want to handle tall arguments.  In that case, I would replace `\mid` with `\,\middle|\,` so that you could achieve the following, which works in both text style and display style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\P(#1){\Phelper#1|\relax\Pchoice(#1)}
\def\Phelper#1|#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax\def\Pchoice{\Pone}\else\def\Pchoice{\Ptwo}\fi}
\def\Pone(#1){\Pr\left( #1 \right)}
\def\Ptwo(#1|#2){\Pr\left( #1 \,\middle|\, #2 \right)}
\def\Pr{\mathbf{Pr}}
\begin{document}
\centering$\P(A)$ or $\P(A|B)$

\[\P(\displaystyle\frac{x}{2}>1 | x>0) = 0.5\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It's necessary to differentiate the argument because the non-`\mid` vertical bar does not look right.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you gain too much by having `\P(A|B)` in the source rather than `\P{A|B}`. Also, redefining `\P` is not a good idea.

Anyway, here's a redefinition of `\Pr`, which exploits `mathtools` so it can receive an optional size argument or the `*` that denotes automatic resizing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand\Pr{sO{}r()}{%
  \operatorname{Pr}%
  \begingroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\PrInn*{#3}}
    {\PrInn[#2]{#3}}%
  \endgroup
}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\PrInn[1](){%
  \activatebar
  #1%
}

\newcommand{\activatebar}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`|
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\;\delimsize\vert\;}%
  \mathcode`|=\string"8000
}

\begin{document}
\[
\Pr(a)\quad
\Pr(x|y)\quad
\Pr[\big](x|y)\quad
\Pr*(\frac{X}{2}|\frac{Y}{2})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great piece of code! May I ask why redefining `\P` is not a good idea? I also redefine it and would be happy to know of side effects I didn't think of.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on this

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\providecommand\given{} % so it exists
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\PH[1](){
   \renewcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:}
   #1
}
\newcommand\Prop{\operatorname{Pr}\PH}
```

Then use

```
\[
    \Prop{ A } \qquad \text{or}\qquad \Prop{ A \given B}
\]
```

this include auto scaling of `()` and `\vert` if you use `\Prop*`. The very recent `mathtools` has a macro to make `\Prop` at one go.

Note I do not make the `()` a part of the syntax, and I perfer space around the `|`

Comment: @ daleif: Why not simply `DeclarePairedDelimiter\Prob[1](){\providecommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:}#1 }`?

Comment: (1) my bad, has to be `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`, (2) yours is not enough, you cannot get the `Pr` in front. That is what the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` from the latest very `mathtools` can do.

Comment: (1) yes, sorry for the typo. Thanks for the information about \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `\left ..\mid ...\right` in this simple case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\P(#1){\expandafter\P@i#1||\@nil}
\def\P@i#1|#2|#3\@nil{\ifx\relax#2\relax \Pr(#1)\else\Pr( #1|#2 )\fi}
\def\Pr{\mathbf{Pr}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\P(A)$ or $\P(A|B)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice succinct macro to achieve the desired result, thanks. However, I prefer the extra spacing when using `\mid`, that's why I did not just write `\Pr(A|B)` in the first place.

Comment: Feel free to use it. Changing the above code is easy

Answer (score 0):

If your main interest is to *replace* `|` with `\mid` if it exists, you can perform a search-and-replace via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright,etoolbox,xparse}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Pr}{R(){}}{%
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \def\pr@arg{#1}\patchcmd{\pr@arg}{|}{\mid}{}{}%
  \mathbf{Pr}\mleft(\pr@arg\mright)%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\Pr(A)$ or $\Pr(A|B)$ or $\Pr(\frac{1}{2}|\frac{2}{3})$

\end{document}
```

Note that `\displaystyle` will typically cause problems with the vertical size of `|` (or `\mid`). Perhaps a replacement could also be `\,\middle|\,`.