# Automatic brace sizes with braket and mathtools

Tags: mathtools, braket

The packages `braket` and `mathtools` provide two different command to typeset set with dynamically sized braces.

For example with `braket`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \set{ \frac{x}{2} | x > 5 }$
$\displaystyle \Set{ \frac{x}{2} | x > 5 }$  
\end{document}
```

And the example with `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\setc[2]{\{}{\}}{\,#1 \;\delimsize\vert\; #2\,}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \setc{ \frac{x}{2} }{ x > 5 }$
$\displaystyle \setc*{ \frac{x}{2} }{ x > 5 }$
$\displaystyle \setc[\bigg]{ \frac{x}{2} }{ x > 5 }$
\end{document}
```

(`setc` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448#124781)

I am currently using `braket` for its nicer interface.  However, recently I found that in same cases I'd like to specify the bracket size manually as in the third case of the `mathtools` example.  Is it somehow possible to combine the features of both packages into one command?

Comment: May be you would like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182933/21930.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks, the second answer looks like what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xparse` on the same basis, here  is a solution  that allows a more natural syntax – at least closer to what one writes by hand: `\set{x ; P(x)}`. More over it lets one type enumerated sets, such as `\set{1, 2, 3,…}`. The only constraint is that if you have to use `;` in the argument of \set, you have to write it as `{;}`.

I also rewrite `\set*` as `\Set`, and chose to define a default optional argument to `\set` with a classical trick – namely `\big`. My experience learnt me that plain \set looks generally too small. However, if you need or want it, you'll just have to write `\set[]`.

Any way, this is the demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\,}}

%% The following makes \big the default for the \set command:
\let\oldset\set
\def\set{\futurelet\testchar\MaybeOptArgSet}
\def\MaybeOptArgSet{\ifx[\testchar \let\next\OptArgSet
\else \let\next\NoOptArgSet \fi \next}
\def\OptArgSet[#1]#2{\oldset[#1]{#2}}
\def\NoOptArgSet#1{\OptArgSet[\big]{#1}}

\def\Set{\oldset*}%

%%% Syntax: \set{x ; P(x)})
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   & \set{x ; x > 5} & & \Set{x ; x > 5}\\[4pt]
   & \set[\bigg]{ \frac{x}{2} ; x > 5} & & \Set{ \frac{x}{2} ; x > 5}\\[4pt]
 & \set[\Bigg]{ \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dotsm} & & \Set{ \mfrac{1}{2},\mfrac{1}{3},\mfrac{1}{4},\dotsm}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing an alternitive solution. Do you use this also in your own documents or is it crafted just for me?

Comment: I made it a series of little things like that for a friend of mine, with a semi-colon as a set-builder symbol, but use your version for my documents. I guess I should use a key-value system to let the choice of the symbol to the final user.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the hint from @Manuel and @egreg's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182943/45603 I found a nice solution.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\set{sO{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\setInn*{#3}}
    {\setInn[#2]{#3}}%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\setInn[1]\{\}{%
  \activatebar
  #1%
}
\newcommand{\activatebar}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`|
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\;\delimsize\vert\;}%
  \mathcode`|=\string"8000
}
\newcommand\Set{\set*}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \set{ \frac{x}{2} | x > 5 }$
$\displaystyle \set*{ \frac{x}{2} | x > 5 }$
$\displaystyle \set[\bigg]{ \frac{x}{2} | x > 5 }$
$\displaystyle \Set{ \frac{x}{2} | x > 5 }$  
\end{document}
```

(Kudos to cargo cult programming)